# Prove the identity $[L_X,L_Y]\omega=L_{[X,Y]}\omega$ for the Lie derivative of a $k$-form $\omega$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, lie-derivative

Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Show that for $\omega$, a $k$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $(L_XL_Y-L_YL_X)\omega=L_{[X,Y]}\omega $.

I try using Cartan's magic formula and get that

$\begin{align}
(L_XL_Y-L_YL_X)\omega &= (L_XL_Y)\omega-(L_YL_X)\omega \\
&= L_X(L_Y\omega)-L_Y(L_X\omega) \\ 
&= L_X(i_Yd\omega+d(i_Y\omega))-L_Y(i_X(d\omega)+d(i_X\omega)) \\
&= i_Xdi_Yd\omega+i_Xd^2(\cdot) + di_Xi_Yd\omega+di_Xdi_Y\omega \\
&- i_Ydi_Xd\omega-i_Yd^2(\cdot) - di_Yi_Xd\omega-di_Ydi_X\omega \\
&= i_Xdi_Yd\omega + di_Xi_Yd\omega+di_Xdi_Y\omega - i_Ydi_Xd\omega - di_Yi_Xd\omega-di_Ydi_X\omega \\
&= [i_Xdi_Y-i_Ydi_X]d\omega+d[i_Xi_Y-i_Yi_X]d\omega+d[i_Xdi_Y-i_Ydi_X]\omega
\end{align}$

For the other part I get

$L_{[X,Y]}\omega=i_{[X,Y]}d\omega+di_{[X,Y]}\omega$

From here I am now stuck.

For the first part of the question (which I have not posted) you are asked (and I am able to) show that $(L_XL_Y-L_YL_X)f=L_{[X,Y]}f$. Not sure whether this is relevant to my question about $\omega$.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $L_X\omega(Z_1,\dots,Z_k)$? Just compute! Or use $L_X\omega = i_X(d\omega) + d(i_X\omega)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now apply the magic formula again:
$$
L_X(\eta)=i_Xd\eta+di_X\eta
$$
where $\eta=i_Yd\omega+di_Y\omega$
and get
$$
L_X(L_Y\omega)=i_Xd(i_Yd\omega+di_Y\omega)+di_X(i_Yd\omega+di_Y\omega)
$$
use that $d$ is linear
$$
i_Xd(i_Yd\omega)+i_X(di_Y\omega)+di_X(i_Yd\omega)+di_X(di_Y\omega)
$$
Subtract $L_Y L_X\omega$ and compare with
$$
L_{[X,Y]}\omega=i_{[X,Y]}d\omega++di_{[X,Y]}\omega
$$
(you should prove:)
$$
[L_X,i_Y]=[i_X,L_Y]=i_{[X,Y]}
$$