# Lie bracket of Lie derivatives is equal to Lie derivatives of the bracket

Tags: differential-geometry

For two vector fields $X$ and $Y$, and the corresponding Lie derivatives $L_X$ and $L_Y$ show:
$$
[L_X,L_Y] = L_XL_Y-L_YL_X=L_{[X,Y]}.
$$
I have a proof using coordinate expressions, which is lengthy and not so elegant, not even sure if each step is correct. I am curious about other solutions mostly about the solutions using integral curves and flows. I found a short proof in LaFontaine's book, which required quite a bit of background. I wan wondering if one can derive this more directly and intuitively.

Comment: The proof I know uses the fact that the Lie bracket of vector fields is invariant uder diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the identity $[L_X,L_Y]\omega=L_{[X,Y]}\omega$ for the Lie derivative of a $k$-form $\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059095/prove-the-identity-l-x-l-y-omega-l-x-y-omega-for-the-lie-derivative-of-a)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The prove this identity, it seems that we should prove it for tensor fields, and not $k-$forms only.  So that solution would not apply. Is this correct?